# Setting up Firebase for a Xamarin Project

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin

I am trying to setup firebase push notifications for my xamarin project, everything seems to be in order however I am currently getting a build error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtmXk.png)

What can I try from here? I used this video on Youtube as a reference https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7w2q2D6mR7g

Answer (score 0):

I had 2 [Application] Tags within my android project. I just had to remove one.